# Exercise on stopping time, Doob decomposition and Martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

> Let X be a square integrable martingale with square variation process $\langle X\rangle$. Let $\tau$ be a finite stopping time. Show the following:
>
> If $E(\langle X\rangle)<\infty$, then
>
> $E((X_\tau-X_0)^2)=E(\langle X\rangle_\tau)$ and $E(X_\tau)=E(X_0)$

In my attempted solution I used the **following definitions:**
Let's consider the probability space $\Omega,\mathbb{F},P$, where $\mathscr{F}_k$ for $k=0,1,2,3...$ are the filtrations of $\mathbb{F}$.

$\langle X\rangle_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}E((X_k-X_{k-1})^2|\mathscr{F}_{k-1})$

**Attempted proof**:

So $E(\langle X\rangle_\tau)=E(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\tau}E((X_k-X_{k-1})^2|\mathscr{F}_{k-1}))=E(\mathbb{1}_\Omega\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\tau}E((X_k-X_{k-1})^2|\mathscr{F}_{k-1}))=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\tau}E((X_k-X_{k-1})^2)=E(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\tau}(X_k-X_{k-1})^2)=E((X_\tau-X_0)^2)$

Regarding $E(X_\tau)=E(X_0)$, I have read in a similar question that I should use the martingale definition since $X_{\tau\wedge n}$ is a martingale by the optional sampling theorem. However I am not seeing how to solve it.

**Questions:**

Is my solution insofar right? How should I prove the second point $E(X_\tau)=E(X_0)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that in your solution, $$\sum_{k=1}^\tau E((X_k - X_{k-1})^2)$$ is a random variable while all the other expressions in that sequence of equations are non-random.  This should tell you something went wrong.

Comment: If $\{Y_n\}$ is a martingale then $EY_n$ is independent of $n$. So $EX_{\tau \wedge n} =EX_{\tau \wedge 0}=EX_0$.

Comment: For the second point : your martingale is bounded in $L^2$, hence by Doob inequalities, the supremum is also in $L^2$, hence in $L^1$. Thus $X_{\tau \wedge n}$ is uniformly integrable (being bounded by the - integrable - supremum of the process) and the optional stopping time theorem applies. I reckon this is a bit cumbersome...

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for your comment but I am not understanding why $EX_{\tau\wedge n}=EX_{\tau\wedge 0}$. Which property are you using? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Olivier Thanks Oliver. I got your point since I had already studied functional analysis. My problem lies from that point forwards. I guess it is the doubt I asked Kavi Rama Murthy.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Could you please expand more on the issue you are mentioning. I am not understanding the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since $\tau$ is a stopping time, $(X_{\tau \wedge n})_n$ is a martingale (this must be in your lecture !), which entails $E[X_{\tau \wedge n}]=E[X_0]$. Now you would like to take the $n \to \infty$ limit  under the expectation : for this you need to check some additional assumption. One possibility is to apply dominated convergence theorem, by first noticing the supremum of the process is integrable, given your assumptions : this is the non trivial part I am alluding to.

Comment: $\tau \wedge 0=0$ because $\tau \geq 0$.

Comment: In your "attempted proof," you write in one step $$\sum_{k=1}^\tau E((X_k - X_{k-1})^2) = E\left(\sum_{k=1}^\tau (X_k - X_{k-1})^2\right).$$  I am saying that this (and the previous equality) cannot _possibly_ be true, since the former is random (the upper limit on the sum is the random variable $\tau$) while the latter is non-random (being an expectation).

I.e. at a bare minimum, your attempted solution must not mix up random elements with non-random elements, and if you ever find yourself writing $$\text{something random } = \text{ something non-random}$$ then your solution isn't valid.

Comment: This type of cursory check of your work is what some of my professors called a "sanity check".  It doesn't tell you whether your work is correct, but it can very quickly tell you when something is obviously wrong (often without requiring any specific knowledge about the problem itself)